# Вывод массива на экран

Tags: c++

Что нужно сделать.

> Ввести с клавиатуры массив, выполнить преобразования данных, вывести на экран массив с помощью функции форматированного вывода printf().
> Написать программу, которая выводит минимальный элемент введенного с клавиатуры массива целых чисел. Двумерный массив вещественных чисел.

Так вот теперь сам код программы, который у меня получается, но не происходит вывод массива на экран + ко всему цикл вроде как тоже не верен:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Работа со строками
#include <string.h>

// Библиотека следящая за выделением памяти
#define _CRTDB_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

int _tmain(int argo, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    // Функция находящая все утечки памяти
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    //  Функция отвечающая за русский язык
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Программа для вычисления минимального элемента массива n");
    printf("              введенного с клавиатурыn");

    float a[3][3] = { 0 };
    float b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1) {
            printf("Введите элемент массива\n");
            scanf("%f", &b);
            a[i][j] = b;
        }
        printf("%f\n", a[i][j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Очень много лишнего. Не обращайте внимания: С++ начал изучать три дня назад.

Answer (score 1):

Убрав все лишнее, ваша текущая программа может быть упрощена до такого:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

float a[3][3];
float b;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1) {
        printf("Введите элемент массиваn");
        scanf("%f", &b);
        a[i][j] = b;
    }

    printf("%fn", a[i][j]);
}
```

**Несколько наводящих вопросов:**

- В каком именно из циклов будет выполняться `printf(... a[i][j])`?
- Откуда появился формат вывода `"%fn"`? Знакомы ли вы с синтаксисом форматирования вещественных чисел при выводе c использованием `printf`?

Comment: Я только второй день в данной сфере пытаюсь чему то научиться. Посмотрел около 20 видео на youtube, там все делают все по разному. У всех свой стиль. Знаю что %f отвечает за вещественное число, а что такое %fn первый раз вижу.
printf(... a[i][j] если относительно задания, то не знаю, а если относительно того что Вы написали, то во втором.

Comment: @ek8800 В том коде, который вы написали стоит `"%fn"` *(хотя, наверно хэшкод так распарсил `\n`, так что неважно).* Короче говоря, ваш текущий вариант кода выведет только 3 элемента на экран. Исправьте его так, чтобы вывелись все элементы.

Comment: @ek8800 После этого разделите ваш текущий цикл на 2 разных - в одном пусть происходит ввод, в другом - вывод (запускать вы их должны друг за другом).

Comment: @ek8800 Третий и финальный шаг - добавить еще один цикл, в котором будет находиться минимальный элемент из всего массива. Этот шаг, понятное дело, вставляется между шагами из предыдущих комментариев.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь